# Array de enteros se cae despues de ejecucion

Tags: c#, array, visual-studio

Tengo un array de enteros que debe cambiar su valor a cada vez que una funcion lo ejecuta.

El problema esque cada vez que este se ejecuta, al pasar del numero 1, este me dice  `Index was outside the bounds of the array`

Este es mi codigo:

```
private const int n = 3;
private const int k = 4;
private static int[] workArr;


for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
{
    int size = (int)Math.Pow(2, i);
    workArr = new int[i];  

    GenerateVariationsWithRep(i); //aqui es donde se cae y me muestra el error

}   



private static void GenerateVariationsWithRep(int length, int index = 0)
{           

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        workArr[index] = i; //selon el debug, me dice que aqui esta mal cuando index e i son iguales a 1
        GenerateVariationsWithRep(index + 1, length);
    }
}
```

Lo que busco esque a cada vez que se ejecute la funcion `GenerateVariationsWithRep()` el array `workArr` cambie y asigne los valores 1,2 y 3.

Como podria arreglarlo?

Gracias

Comment: No deberías en tu primer "if" usar la variable de control "i" a 0 algo así ? for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)

Comment: @OmarViñas, intente con iniciarla con 0 pero me sice arrojando el error Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema está cuando estableces el tamaño del array workArr:

```
workArr = new int[i];
```

ya que, por ejemplo, cuando i = 1 se ejecuta la función `GenerateVariationsWithRep(1)` y debido a que `n = 3` y el tamaño del array es 1, te genera el error. Creo que debes poner:

```
workArr = new int[size];
```

Comment: Hola, ya cambie el valor del array a size y se me cae en el mismo lugar

Answer (score 0):

Los array en C#, como en otros lenguajes, estan basados en cero. Eso quiere decir que el primer item del mismo, esta en la posicion 0.

Como estas pidiendo que copie el valor en la posicion 1, en la primera corrida va a fallar.

Prueba poniendo a index como igual a 0 y va a funcionar (aunque no con mucho sentido, siempre vas a copiar al primer lugar lo que estas pasando)

```
private static void GenerateVariationsWithRep(int length, int index = 0)
```

Comment: hola, si ya intente lo mismo y me da el mismo resultado. Se cae nuevamente

Comment: podes aclarar que error te da?

Comment: Me da el mismo error Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: Hola. En Visual Studio puedes realizar una configuración para que la ejecución de tu programa se detenga en la línea que produce una excepción. Configura VS con lo que se comenta en [Administración de excepciones con el depurador](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/x85tt0dd.aspx). Con esto, en el momento que se pare el programa realiza una revisión de las variables involucradas en el método inclusive te recomiendo una ejecución paso a paso del mismo

Comment: De todas formas, veo en tu código que la llamada recursiva dentro del bucle `for` tiene los parámetros cambiados de lugar. Revísalo. Necesitas también implementar una condición en tu método recursivo para que salga de la recursión. Si no la tienes puedes provocar un desbordamiento de la pila.

Answer (score -1):

por que no ocupas genéricos mejor `List<int> tuMatriz =new List<int>()` te quitas todos los problemas